# transition visual effect from the bottom for table search

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchresultscontroller

Is it possible to controll the transition visual effect from the bottom for table search ?

I want to make this effect :

[image]

Comment: use present and dismissviewcontroller

Comment: is not a custom table . is the table with results from search bar

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is was i did for this :

```
CATransition *transDown=[CATransition animation];
        [transDown setDuration:0.1];
        [transDown setType:kCATransitionPush];
        [transDown setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
        [transDown setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

        [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.layer addAnimation:transDown forKey:nil];
        [self.search.layer addAnimation:transDown forKey:nil];
```